# How to submit form from javascript include inside of a .net page

Tags: php, javascript, .net

Forgive my ignorance of .Net, php/python programmer here.  I am providing a client who uses .Net with a javascript include that contains a form. When I provided the first iteration of this javascript include, the form submission was being intercepted by .Net and so it wasn't properly submitting where it should.  I've been trying to read up on what's at issue here, but the best I can figure out is that the whole page is wrapped in a form and so the .Net form wrapper is intercepting any children form submissions.  So, I have since changed the code to have event listeners on the form object itself that is being included and thus forcing the form to submit properly.  What I am wondering is, will this even work, or is there something I'm missing?  Any enlightenment would be appreciated as this particular client is difficult and I don't want to send them something that doesn't work.

Comment: wouldn't really help to add code, it's a conceptual question.  A client is including my javascript include that contains a form and their .Net is intercepting the form.  I need to get around that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the whole page was wrapped in a form.  After swapping out the form tags for a div and listening for key code = 13 on the input boxes or click of the submit button, I then iterated over all the form elements before manually submitting the form.